# Definir variable object

Tags: javascript, ionic, angular, typescript

Sé que el error está en cómo se define usuario, ¿cómo haría para definirlo como un tipo object?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Proveedor1Provider } from '../../providers/proveedor1/proveedor1';
import { AboutPage } from '../about/about';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    usuarios="";

    constructor(public toastCtrl: ToastController, public navCtrl: NavController, public provedor: Proveedor1Provider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {}

    getItems(ev) {
        var val = ev.target.value;
        if(val.length > 1){

            this.provedor.obtenerDatos(val)
            .subscribe(
                (data)=> {this.usuarios = data},
                (error)=> {console.log(error);}
                )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque no defines la variable como let o var?

Comment: intentastes definirlo algo como `usuarios = {}` a proposito tu problema no es IONIC es JavaScript

Comment: Si sólo deja el nombre, también funciona... usuarios borrale el = las "" y el ;

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR: `usuarios: any = ''`

Estas teniendo un problema de TypeScript, no de Jvascript. Como puede que ya sepás, estas definiendo `usuarios` como `string`. Para definirlo como tipo `object` tienes que darle el tipo `any`.

En TypeScript puedes definir el tipo de variable de manera explícita e implícita.

Cuando haces `usuarios = ''` estas definiendo de manera implícita a `usuarios` como `string`. Esto también podés hacerlo de manera explícita con `usuarios: string = ''`, de esa manera le dices al compilador de TypeScript que tipo de variable usarás.

Ahora para darle cualquier valor (como `object`) usas `: any` (any significa cualquiera).

Answer (score 0):

tienes que crear una interfaz de usuario,
por ejemplo:
      
      `interface Usuario { 
      nombre: string;
      apellido: string
    }`

después en tu clase HomePage defines tu variable usuarios de esta forma:
    
    `usuarios: Array<Usuario> = [];`

De esta forma estas indicando que la variable usuarios es un array del tipo usuario

Comment: Pero Array<> es sintaxis de Java o no?

Comment: En las versiones de Angular 2 en adelante, puedes usar 'var: Array<Object>' ya que es typescript, un traspiler de JS. en la version Angular JS se declara el array de esta forma: 'var = new Array("x", "z", "z");'

Comment: Ok gracias por el dato